# Step-function Fit with Three Values for a Given Graph

Tags: interpolation, step-function

Given a graph how can we find a step-function that can only take three values to best fit the graph?

For example, [given this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygkq5.png), where the function we want to fit is the one in black. What is the process of finding the three values for y (in the graph y=4, 6, and 8) and the intervals for each of these values to best optimize the fit?

The closest thing I found to this is the [1-dimensional nearest-neighbor interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation), but I couldn't find an algorithm for that or a way for the fit to take only three values as I want.

I realize how bad my example is. If possible I just want a qualitative description of how one could find a good fit given these restrictions.

Comment: What do you mean by "taking three values"?

Comment: The step function takes only three y values. In the example, the fit only took the values y= 4, 6, and 8.